# how to get value from hidden input type array using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, input, hidden

How to get value from hidden input type array my input is below and i am trying this code

```
  <input type="hidden" name="POSITION[]" value="10">
  var arr= $('input[type="hidden"][name="POSITION[]"]').val();
```

Comment: You code should work, http://jsfiddle.net/xvy6cta9/

Answer (score 4):

Try this code

```
var arr = $('input[type="hidden"][name="POSITION[]"]').map(function(){
  return this.getAttribute("value");
}).get();
```